# Flutter get error when run on the real device

Tags: dart, flutter

im using flutter when to run on the real iphone device i get bellow error
when i run bellow mentioned commands i get the same error

- brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies libimobiledevice
- brew install --HEAD libimobiledevice
- brew install ideviceinstaller

> ```
> [!] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 10.0)
>     • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
>     • Xcode 10.0, Build version 10A255
>     ✗ Verify that all connected devices have been paired with this computer in Xcode.
>       If all devices have been paired, libimobiledevice and ideviceinstaller may require updating.
>       To update, run:
>         brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies libimobiledevice
>         brew install --HEAD libimobiledevice
>         brew install ideviceinstaller
>     • ios-deploy 2.0.0
>     • CocoaPods version 1.5.3
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably hitting the issue described at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/22595.

Can you try to make sure you update usbmuxd as well? You should be able to run:

```
brew update
brew uninstall libimobiledevice
brew uninstall usbmuxd
brew install --HEAD usbmuxd
brew install --HEAD libimobiledevice
```